# Inconsistent UILabel font size in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

What's the best way to maintain a consistent font size for the `UILabels` circled below? Ideally all red pricing labels should have the same font size as the DKK1,742 one.

[image]

In the case of a price such as "$24" (3 characters versus 8), the font size will be larger. Is there a way to dynamically calculate the smallest font size for the set of prices, and then use that one consistently?

One additional data point is that logging (within our custom `UITableViewCell`)

> [[self averagePricePerNightLabel] font]

always yields:

> font-family: "Helvetica";
>   font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your labels have `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` set to true? If so this is expected behavior. Make your font sizes smaller and it should fix stuff.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is set to true but for a reason. In the case of a price such as $24, the font size needs to be bigger. Is there a way to dynamically calculate the smallest font size, and then use that one consistently?

Comment: You can calculate the size of of a string using NSString's sizeWithFont: method but you would have to do that yourself.